# Получить название программы, которая по умолчанию запускает файл

Tags: c#, windows

Имеется проект WinForms, при нажатии на кнопку хочу открывать файл приложением по умолчанию. Приложение по умолчанию имеет возможность открывать в одном окне несколько файлов.

[image: Вкладки открытых файлов в программе.]

Мне необходимо при открытии этих файлов в этой программе выводить название самой программы.

Использую следующий подход:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
   UseShellExecute = true,
   FileName = file.WorkFileName
};
process.Start();
MessageBox.Show(process.MainWindowTitle);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Но при открытии нового файла в уже открытом приложении появляется ошибка:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "Нет процессов, связанных с этим объектом."
```

В свою очередь файл открывается в этой программе, но при попытке получить полное название открывающей программы выводится ошибка выше. Помимо этого `process.WaitForExit();` блокирует доступ к моей программе на WinForms, пока я не закрою файл, если я уберу эту строку, то я вообще никак не могу получить название программы.

Как я могу открывать файлы в программе и не смотря на то, что она уже работает получать ее название? Просто есть несколько программ, которые открывают данный формат, и у каждого пользователя используется разная версия этих программ.

Comment: Операционная система Windows

Comment: Мне кажется немного странным смотреть на заголовок окна, для того, чтоб понять открывать в этой программе свой файл или нет. У вас наверно есть путь до исполняемого файла, а у исполняемого файла в свойствах есть наверно и версия, и название, и компания наверно создавшая продукт. Может стоит в эту сторону копать?